# Upsert in mongoengine is not generating ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to execute an upsert function in **mongoengine**. That is, if a document is present, I want to update it with new values, and if it isn't present, I want to create and insert.

I have list of objects. These objects can or cannot have ObjectIds. **Example is:**

```
[
    {
        "id" : ObjectId("5c1791b7397df4a9c8518342"),
        "type": "Line"
    },
    {
        "type": "Line"
    }
]
```

As you can see the second object does not have an Id.

**I have written my query as:**

```py
updates = Collection.objects(
    id=obj.get('id', None)).modify(
        new=True, 
        upsert= True, 
        **update_dict
    )
```

`obj` is each object when I iterate through the list.

Note: `update_dict` is another dict that gets its value from a function that returns the attributes to set. (For example: set__type: "Line")

**Problem**

The first object is getting modified just fine. However there is an error:

> "'None' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a
>   24-character hex string"

Clearly it's because of the `obj.get('id', None)` part.

**So, is there a way that an id can be generated if it is passed as None?**

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing with mongoose and nodejs and it works for me if i am using like below:

Here is i my array Object:

```
           var arr = [
                {
                    _id: "5c13de7d47zfe91e3484362f",
                    email: 'test1@gmail.com',
                },
                {
                    _id: "5c13de7d47zfe91e3484362f",
                    email: 'test2@gmail.com',
                },
                {
                    // _id: "5c66aa87751fz5368759f9bc",   // Commented 
                    email: 'test3@gmail.com',
                }
            ]
```

Now i am iterating through the array as below with nodejs.

```
        arr.forEach(async element => {
            await Driver.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    _id: Types.ObjectId(element._id) 
                },
                {
                    email: element.email
                },{ upsert: true, new: true }
            ).lean().exec();
        });
```

And it works for me. It's updating documents in first two cases and inserting new doc for last case. 
The main thing is to use `Types.ObjectId`  which is used to specify a type of ObjectId. If i am doing it without specifying `Schema.Types.ObjectId` then it does not working.